# Getting feedback from 200 People without calling them

Tags: excel

I do not know if this is the right Stack page to write this to but:
The Problem I am facing is that I have an Excel file with the names of people in my company and the licences they hold for certain pieces of Software. This list is getting updatet frequently but there are obiously people in there that have licences to Software that they probably do not use anymore. How can I reach out to all the people in this excel sheet and get feedback on if they are still using the software licence without having to call each and everyone of them?

Answer (score 1):

1. step extract your sheet to csv or some sort of db.
2. make app that will let users to select if they are using that software or not.
3. save the data inside new sheet